# Should I use industry related terms when choosing a domain name for best SEO results?

Tags: seo, domains

I am going to create new website. I will do onpage & Offpage SEO both. I just want to know that how should I choose domain name?

Which domain will have more SEO effect? Like If I am going to create website for QA-Testing services then should I choose domain related to QA field? OR It can be other name?

Comment: @John - How can I write more specific? Because I have already defied all specific things like domain for QA/Testing website and SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pick a top level domain if possible. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains
2. Try to chose a shorter domain name. That will make it easier for users to remember and it will let you add more characters into the URL.
3. Do not chose a spammy looking domain like example-example-example.com. Too many hyphens looks spammy. Avoid .biz and others like this. They also look spammy and your CTR (Click Through Rate) will suffer.
4. Google explicitly says that if you are trying to hack a domain name to make it a novelty, like http://google.it or http://searchnoi.se be aware that Google will think the site pertains more closely to the country that those extensions are assigned to. Matt Cutt's speaks here on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJqZIH_0Ars
5. Audit your potential domain by going to http://archive.org/ and viewing its history.
6. Do a back link audit for the potential domain to make sure someone did not spam with it and then discard the domain.
7. Some tests show "exact match domains" chicagopizza.com still have a minor advantage. In my opinion, the brand is more important and I would stick with my brand name in the domain name.

Comment: Can you please suggest good domain for QA/Testing service provider ?

Comment: Hi Rahul, my pleasure. I am a little confused. Most QA people do not want their domains they test on to be discoverable in search engines. So, for those you could name it what you like and noindex the site. If you are asking about your main website for you actual company, it depends on a lot of things. If you have a brand already and can purchase the .com that matches, I would do so.

Comment: Yes I would like to setup company website. We will provide software testing and all other testing related services.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. My answer is that it has to be short, memorable, and easy to type in; plus be unique enough to be used in building a brand. If you're just going for small add revenue, a generic name, like weselldomains.com might generate substantial traffic without much effort and even do better than a uniquely branded domain in the short run. But in the long run, for actual market penetration it has to meet the qualifications I gave.  A DIY home blogger might stumble on weselldomsins.com but to get a large portion of the market you need to sell an image of your company to consumers and that requires a brand and a domain that is easily associated with that brand.

As far as SEO goes. Google is who to impress and their algorithms get stronger and stronger. The question their proprietary algorithm and search engine spider bots are trying to accurately answer is, is this actually a webpage that people want to see at the top of their search results.

Short term: weselldomains.com is ranked better than a custom branded name. If they both launch on the same day.

Long term: wellselldomains.com will never compete with GoDaddy.com because they have penetrated the market and googles algorithm measures the internets actual interest of a site to determine its ranking.

In summery pick the unique URL thar matches your branding over a domain that has industry buzz words in it. Have pristine Programing throughout your website and provide relevant useful information then use all types of media (especially social i.e. Facebook, YouTube) to actually engage with your target and update with new content regularly. As real interest grows, traffic will follow and rankings will increase bringing more interest and traffic and further increasing your ranking.

Comment: Eric - Thanks a lot for nice answer and great information.

Comment: Yes sir. It's interesting that they put your question here on hold as too broad. I felt like it was a decently specific question. How to pick a domain name w/ qualifications of it generating good SEO results. On a web forum titled "webmasters" I would I think that's just about right. Maybe they are basing it off the questions title alone.